# How to group range of cells into date ranges of "Multiple times per day", Weekly, Monthly etc

Tags: excel-formula

I have a set of data that is shown as such:

| User | Report | Month | Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | Report Name 1 | 2019 Aug | 20/08/2019 |
| User 2 | Report Name 1 | 2019 Aug | 20/08/2019 |
| User 1 | Report Name 2 | 2019 Aug | 21/08/2019 |
| User 2 | Report Name 3 | 2019 Aug | 23/08/2019 |
| User 1 | Report Name 1 | 2019 Aug | 24/08/2019 |
| User 3 | Report Name 2 | 2019 Aug | 30/08/2019 |
| User 3 | Report Name 4 | 2019 Aug | 30/08/2020 |

I am trying to perform some research into how often certain reports are run and group them into the following ranges:

- Used multiple times a day
- Used once daily
- Used Weekly
- Used Monthly
- Used Yearly
- Seldom Used

I don't need to which users are using the reports, just the number.
I've tried countifs but so far i've only been able to count the number of uses per day by creating a new table and de-duplicating the values like so:

| Report | Month | Day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Report Name 1 | 2019 Aug | 20/08/2019 |
| Report Name 2 | 2019 Aug | 21/08/2019 |
| Report Name 3 | 2019 Aug | 23/08/2019 |
| Report Name 1 | 2019 Aug | 24/08/2019 |
| Report Name 2 | 2019 Aug | 30/08/2019 |
| Report Name 4 | 2019 Aug | 30/08/2020 |

Then using Countif: =COUNTIFS(A3:A8,A3,C3:C8,C3)

This formula is only giving me how many uses of each report per date shown in column C. To know what is used daily I also need to eyeball column C and make a best guess that reports are being activated on consecutive days so it would be great if there was a way to factor in weekends and holidays into a formula.

Any help will be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Firstly, Can you be more specific about the groups that you listed? You wrote that you want to conduct research into how often *certain* reports are used but then you seem to ask for a formula to calculate the number of reports fitting into the groups *in general*. Do you only want the quantity of reports that fall into the categories or do you want the formula to spell out the names of those reports?

Comment: Secondly, how should the belonging to a group be measured? For example, let's take the first group 'used multiple times a day'. We could calculate the number of reports for which the daily average of accesses is greater than one, or we could be very strict and only count those that have at least one access in every single day over the observation period, or less strictly we could look at consecutive days over a rolling time window, e.g. 1 month (excl. weekends and holidays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a rather flexible solution that allows you to select different time periods and thresholds and then lists the 'reports' fitting in those selected criteria:

[image]

With the data array (excl. headers) named 'DataArray' and the dates column range named 'DateRange' then  given the example in the screenshot above, the formulas are as follows.

in I12:

```
=LET(FilterArray,FILTER(DataArray,(DateRange>(I$2-I$3))*(DateRange<=I$2)),ReportUnique,UNIQUE(INDEX(FilterArray,0,2),FALSE,FALSE),CountBins,INT(I$3/I$5),StartBins,I$2-SEQUENCE(CountBins,1,I$5,I$5),EndBins,I$2-SEQUENCE(CountBins,1,0,I$5),IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(ReportUnique,TRANSPOSE(MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,CountBins*COUNTA(ReportUnique),1,0),IFERROR((TRANSPOSE(ReportUnique)=INDEX(ReportUnique,INT(SEQUENCE(CountBins*COUNTA(ReportUnique),1,0)/CountBins)+1))*TRANSPOSE(MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(FilterArray),1,0),(INDEX(IF((INDEX(FilterArray,0,4)<=TRANSPOSE(EndBins))*(INDEX(FilterArray,0,4)>TRANSPOSE(StartBins)),INDEX(FilterArray,0,2)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(FilterArray)),TRANSPOSE(MOD(SEQUENCE(CountBins*COUNTA(ReportUnique),1,0),CountBins)+1))=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(ReportUnique,INT(SEQUENCE(CountBins*COUNTA(ReportUnique),1,0)/CountBins)+1)))+0)>=I$6)+0,0)))=CountBins)),"None"))
```

in J12:

```
=LET(FilterArray,FILTER(DataArray,(DateRange>(J$2-J$3))*(DateRange<=J$2)),ReportUnique,UNIQUE(INDEX(FilterArray,0,2),FALSE,FALSE),CountBins,INT(J$3/J$5),StartBins,I$2-SEQUENCE(CountBins,1,I$5,I$5),EndBins,I$2-SEQUENCE(CountBins,1,0,I$5),IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(ReportUnique,TRANSPOSE(MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,CountBins*COUNTA(ReportUnique),1,0),IFERROR((TRANSPOSE(ReportUnique)=INDEX(ReportUnique,INT(SEQUENCE(CountBins*COUNTA(ReportUnique),1,0)/CountBins)+1))*TRANSPOSE(MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(FilterArray),1,0),(INDEX(IF((INDEX(FilterArray,0,4)<=TRANSPOSE(EndBins))*(INDEX(FilterArray,0,4)>TRANSPOSE(StartBins)),INDEX(FilterArray,0,2)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(FilterArray)),TRANSPOSE(MOD(SEQUENCE(CountBins*COUNTA(ReportUnique),1,0),CountBins)+1))=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(ReportUnique,INT(SEQUENCE(CountBins*COUNTA(ReportUnique),1,0)/CountBins)+1)))+0)<J$6)+0,0)))=CountBins)),"None"))
```

in K12:

```
=LET(FilterArray,FILTER(DataArray,(DateRange>(K$2-K$3))*(DateRange<=K$2)),ReportUnique,UNIQUE(INDEX(FilterArray,0,2),FALSE,FALSE),CountBins,INT(K$3/K$5),StartBins,I$2-SEQUENCE(CountBins,1,I$5,I$5),EndBins,I$2-SEQUENCE(CountBins,1,0,I$5),IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(ReportUnique,TRANSPOSE(MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,CountBins*COUNTA(ReportUnique),1,0),IFERROR((TRANSPOSE(ReportUnique)=INDEX(ReportUnique,INT(SEQUENCE(CountBins*COUNTA(ReportUnique),1,0)/CountBins)+1))*TRANSPOSE(MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(FilterArray),1,0),(INDEX(IF((INDEX(FilterArray,0,4)<=TRANSPOSE(EndBins))*(INDEX(FilterArray,0,4)>TRANSPOSE(StartBins)),INDEX(FilterArray,0,2)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(FilterArray)),TRANSPOSE(MOD(SEQUENCE(CountBins*COUNTA(ReportUnique),1,0),CountBins)+1))=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(ReportUnique,INT(SEQUENCE(CountBins*COUNTA(ReportUnique),1,0)/CountBins)+1)))+0))+0,0)))>=K$6)),"None"))
```

and in L12:

```
=LET(FilterArray,FILTER(DataArray,(DateRange>(L$2-L$3))*(DateRange<=L$2)),ReportUnique,UNIQUE(INDEX(FilterArray,0,2),FALSE,FALSE),CountBins,INT(L$3/L$5),StartBins,I$2-SEQUENCE(CountBins,1,I$5,I$5),EndBins,I$2-SEQUENCE(CountBins,1,0,I$5),IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(ReportUnique,TRANSPOSE(MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,CountBins*COUNTA(ReportUnique),1,0),IFERROR((TRANSPOSE(ReportUnique)=INDEX(ReportUnique,INT(SEQUENCE(CountBins*COUNTA(ReportUnique),1,0)/CountBins)+1))*TRANSPOSE(MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(FilterArray),1,0),(INDEX(IF((INDEX(FilterArray,0,4)<=TRANSPOSE(EndBins))*(INDEX(FilterArray,0,4)>TRANSPOSE(StartBins)),INDEX(FilterArray,0,2)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(FilterArray)),TRANSPOSE(MOD(SEQUENCE(CountBins*COUNTA(ReportUnique),1,0),CountBins)+1))=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(ReportUnique,INT(SEQUENCE(CountBins*COUNTA(ReportUnique),1,0)/CountBins)+1)))+0))+0,0)))<L$6)),"None"))
```

Here is another example screnshot with different selections in the input cells: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aObDb.png)

Note that there is no special recognition of weekends or holidays in here yet. I would suggest either reverting to VBA or an extra sheet just for those calculations to include weekend and holiday adjustments.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your help! I won't pretend that I understand what you have put together for me but i've managed to apply it to my data set. For some reason the first three formulas from I12 - K12 keep returning "None" no matter what values I put into the days and Access Threshold fields but the formula in L12 is adjusting per date range I put in. Thank you again, much appreciated!

Comment: Let's test if the I12 formula is working correctly in your data. Can you select a period for which you know that there is one report that has at least one occurrence on every day of that period? Then the formula should list that report if you set 'Bin Width' = 1 and 'Access Threshold' = 1

Comment: As a second test, can you select a period in which any report has an occurrence? The formula should list all report that have any occurence at all when setting 'Bin Width' to the same as the 'Time Window' and 'Access Threshold' = 1.
Vice versa, the J12 formula should show all the remaining one when set to the same values for this test.

Comment: So I changed the time window, bin width and access threshold and yes, I am seeing the reports being run at least once a day when I eyeball the list. I changed the time window to 7 and this then includes the same reports as those run daily but now also includes those run at least once in a 7 day period

Comment: That being said, one of the reports identified as daily is not being run so often but appears to be weekly. Not sure why that is but i'm still looking

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to follow as good as I can to understand if this is indeed an error or just a matter of selecting inputs correctly.
So when you set time window to 7, bin width to 1 and threshold to 1, only reports with at least 1 input each 1 day over a 7 day period should show up with the first formula. Is that not the case?